# What is the easiest way to fetch data dynamically from a cloud storage to a flutter app

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-storage

I am looking for a way to fetch data to my flutter app which can be adjusted and modified dynamically after deploying the app. As an example, if I want to change the images of the carousel depending on promotions or launch new books to the digital library. I need an economic option to host the data in cloud storage and fetch it from there.

I have considered firebase as well as google drive, but have yet to find a good guide. being a beginner and having concerns about security I want some expert advice if possible.

*edit-
Seeing many a tutorial I assume there is no better way than linking file URLs from the
Cloud Storage. So to dynamically change those is it possible to refer the URLs to some excel sheet fields to obtain URLs. Those fields can certainly be adjusted then without any hard coding. but the question is how to refer to such a sheet file? *

I also want to segregate the users into paid and free users, I have successfully proceeded with the authentication with firebase but still don't understand(I do have some concepts but don't know where to do that) how to put them in groups and impose limitations on them about accessing the data. any guidance, links and helpful advice will be cordially appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to what you are looking for, I highly recommend you to use [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config), which is a cloud tool that allows you to modify your app's functionality and appearance without forcing users to download an update. You define in-app default values that control the functionality and appearance of your app when you use Remote Config. Then, for all app users or for subsets of your user base, you may utilize the Firebase console or the Remote Config backend APIs to modify in-app default values.

Your program can control when updates are applied, and it can check for updates regularly and apply them with minimal performance impact.

Remote Config comes with a client library that takes care of essential functions like fetching parameter values and caching them while still allowing you to manage when new values are active and how they affect the user experience in your app.

Here is a [tutorial](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-firebase-remote-config) that uses Flutter and Firebase Remote Config that could also help you.

Comment: Thank you Jose for a descriptive writing. Thank you also for mentioning the terminologies that will help me atleast to look for something. I will surely check the link provided.

Comment: But are changing backend materials and database are equivalent to an update?